# Can someone explain for loop inside for loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua

I'm learning Lua, and while learning FOR loop I had that example:

```
for i = 1, 3 do
  for j = 1, i do
    print(j)
  end
end
```

and that's the output:

```
1
1
2
1
2
3
```

Why is that?

Comment: What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This code is going to loop 3 times in total.

> the first loop will hit the second for loop once as `i == 1` and print 1
>   the second loop will see `i == 2` and so prints 1 and 2
>   the third loop will see `i == 3` and so print 1,2, and 3

This is because `j` is set back to 1 on each loop and therefore prints all numbers 1 through `i` on each loop.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: You're wrong at one point: `j` isn't getting set back to `1`, and further more, when you refer to `j` at the loop body, you're referring to a local added automatically by its own scope (relating to the target iteration variable, not really a variable, but named `j`). Though I'm not sure if you used this term to facilitate the understanding?

Comment: yeah, I just meant every time you hit the second for loop J is equal to 1 and so it prints all numbers between 1 and I